# Store php mysql ajax search engine result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, search-engine

I have been working on a project for a while then my friend asked me to take a look at the
websites search engine aswell.

The search engine is made in php mysql ajax, ajax pagination.

You write a keyword/search word, select category, state, city price then hit search,
like any other search engine.

It all works well BUT lets say you make a search, then click on one of the
"searchresult links" THEN go back from that page to the index (search page) again, your
previous entered search values has cleared as well as the search results from that search query.

So my question now is if anyone got a good tip on how to solve that?
Since its ajax/js the Url stays the same, eg index.php/ and doesnt change when you search for something.

I want to be able to make a search, click on one of the links then go back again but still have my previus search values / results left, so I dont have to fill in the same stuff again.

The code is a bit messy and as soon as I have cleaned it a bit I will post it aswell.

Thanks!

Comment: one of the reason why the old ways are the best ways

Comment: You could change the `window.location.hash` accordingly. But most important: Do not use AJAX just because it's "cool" but only where it makes sense. And in this scenario I do not see a reason why you should use AJAX...

Comment: Agree, its now my own work and my firend really want me to use his code : / 

There is alot of ajax going on.

Works like:
You search something, the search result show up as links, and if you
click on one link, some of that links content will load into a div
like a preview then there is a "read more" botton that now targets
target_blank, but it should be a direct link instead.
So I guess they decided to go full out on ajax since there allready
is so much of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it simple: use a *session*! But, let me demonstrate what I mean.

Suppose the below is your search form.

```
<form method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='search' placeholder='<?php echo  $history' ?> />
  <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

Now, if you want to save every last search keyword inside the input bar, then use a session like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){
   $_SESSION['history'] = $_POST['search'];
   $history = $_SESSION['history'];
}else{
   $history = 'enter your search term';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I will try that.

There is just so many search-values to fill in, and js/ajax stuff like ajax dropdown etc, and changing between listview-mode thumgnail-mode on the result with json.

And it always feels messy when its not your own code hehe

Comment: No problem. But this is pretty neat solution, it will save you lots of time. btw: you have to accept answer when people help you, here in StackOverflow